# Why does casting a short into a byte do this?

Tags: c#, types, casting, byte

Talking about C# here. Following Code:

```
short s = 2323;     
Console.WriteLine((byte)s);
```

Output is 19. Why?

Comment: A short is 2 bytes, a byte is 1 byte. You will lose information/precision. Which output did you expect instead of 19?

Comment: What would you *expect* the output to be, and how did you reach that expectation?

Comment: Yeah... what did you expect to happen? In binary, 2323 would be 00001001 00010011 (two bytes). Dropping the more significant byte, we get 00010011, which is equal to 19 in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

The `short` type stores numbers using 2 bytes in memory and can hold numbers from -32768 to 32767. `ushort` is the unsigned version of this type and can hold numbers from 0 to 65535. 2 bytes comprise 16 bits. 2^16 is 65536.

The `byte` type only uses 1 byte in memory and can represent unsigned numbers from 0 to 255 (in .NET, `byte` is always unsigned). 1 byte comprises 8 bits. 2^8 is 256.

So how do you get from 2 bytes to 1 byte? You strip off/ignore all the bytes that do not fit your target type. The best way to illustrate this is to write the numbers as hex numbers (two hex digits are exactly 1 byte):

- 2323 is 0x0914 – the high byte is 0x09, the lower byte is 0x14
- 19 is 0x14 – there is only 1 byte and its value is 0x14, identical to the lower byte of the short value.